# Не считывается переменная из nodemon.json в режиме отладки

Tags: node.js, nodemon

В режиме debug (VS code) не читается переменная JWT_KEY из файла nodemon.json 
При запуске приложения, все работает корректно. Вопрос, что и как нужно сконфигурировать, чтобы в режиме отладки из nodemon.json считывались переменные в process.env ?

```
nodemon.json 
{
    "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development",
        "MONGO_ATLAS_PWD": "GTL3KferEArNLV9e",
        "JWT_KEY": "secret"
    }
}


launch.js
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "nodemon",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/server.js",
            "restart": true,
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\server.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

При запуске отладчика убедитесь, что выбрана правильная конфигурация (nodemon). Отладчик может быть запущен и с другой конфигурацией, но в этом случае не гарантируется, что переменные из nodemon.json будут загруженны в process.env

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]